# bash: ./wls1036_solaris32.bin: Invalid argument

Tags: bash, webserver, bash-scripting, solaris, oracle-11g

Having some experience in ubuntu, I installed `solaris 11g` recently to work on `WebLogic`. I've downloaded `wls1036_solaris32.bin` file.

When I run `./wls1036_solaris32.bin` in the terminal, I'm getting

`bash: ./wls1036_solaris32.bin: Invalid argument`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you already got your answer in the other [forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2388966&tstart=0) you posted your question to,

> Don't use that. Solaris is 64 bit. The last 32 bit version of Solaris was 2.6 about 10 years ago.
>   Use the generic wls1036_generic.jar installer instead.

Comment: WTF? if that doesn't work why the hell they put it in the download list? Bandwidth doesn't come cheap in the place where I live :'(

Answer (score 1):

32-bit programs still work fine in the latest Solaris. I have seen this kindof confusing error if the file is a SPARC binary trying to run on a system with an x86 chip, or vice versa.